# igraph style arrow for ggplot axis and segment

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, arrows

Is it possible to use `Arrows` header style in `igraph` package for `ggplot` segments and axis lines? There are some options in `grid`, but these options do not yield the arrows in `igraph`.

```
library(igraph)
plot(0, 0, xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
iArrows <- igraph:::igraph.Arrows
iArrows(c(0,0,0.5), c(0,0,0.5), c(0,1,1), c(1,0,1), h.lwd=2, sh.lwd=2, width=1, size=1.5)
  
library(ggplot2)
qplot(0,0,xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), xlab="", ylab="") + theme_classic() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, xend = 1, yend = 1),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

[image]

Comment: The short answer is "no", there is no native option to do this in ggplot. There are many ways to achieve it, but none at the moment are as straightforward as just specifying the arrow type. If you look at the code for `igraph:::igraph.Arrows`, you can see that it calculates the necessary curves as polygons and draws them in base graphics. One could write something similar in grid to use in ggplot, but this seems like a lot of work for a minor embellishment.